# How to get rid of cos-nonambig schema error while generating java source from wsdl with cxf 2.2.12

Tags: java, validation, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

Hi I have a problem while generating source code from this wsdl https://mollusk.atollon.com//scheduler.wsdl . My question is:

1. is it possible to get rid of the cos-nonambig error and generate source code?
2. as validating of wsdl went fine is there any other tool which I can use to find where exactly is this cos-nonambig problem?